# How to stop loading pdf on mobile device?

Tags: javascript, css

I have object element in xhtml page. I load pdf file into this object. I need to disable loading of this object on mobile device. When hiding this object by CSS means it is still loaded.

How to stop loading pdf on mobile device? I need a solution in pure CSS/JS - ie on browser side. Changing xhtml to not to have object element on server side is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the problems:

```js
if (!("application/pdf" in navigator.mimeTypes) && $("#pdf_element").length > 0) {
    $("#pdf_element").remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers automatically download any asset they can. The best solution would be to remove the object from the DOM using JS.

```
// check if mobile element then:
$( "#pdf_element" ).remove();
```

Comment: `$(window).on("beforeunload", function(){
    if ($("#pdf_element").length > 0)
 {
     if ($(window).width() < 480 || $(window).height() < 480) {
  $("#pdf_element").remove();
     }
 }`

Comment: beforeunload is used when the user is LEAVING the page. You want this when the page is loaded. Try something like this: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Thank you. I used check existing index "application/pdf" in array mimeTypes.